# Built-in way to name one specific celery task

Tags: django, celery

I'm using Celery with Django (and django-db as result backend).

I know that it's possible to give names to registered tasks using `@app.task(name='My Task')` but that's only like categorizing.

Assume uploading and processing a file "batch-210520.json". I want to be able to identify one running task as the task which is processing that specific file.
Obviously I could add my own table to keep track of task ids and their unique names, but if there is a built-in way I want to use it.

Unfortunately I only found the solution for naming the whole registered task.

Comment: Celery does not run a process per file (parameter). It has a pool of "workers" that wait for a task, process it, and then wait for the next item.

Comment: In the celery table however, every "call" to the function got a UUID, this is also the UUID you retrieve, for example to later cancel the task.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know about the fact from comment 1 and number 2 is the thing I refer to. I don't only want an UUID but also a unique - human readable, understandable - name. Using bind=true gives me something like self.request.id, so I am able to retrieve the task-id inside the called function. I just need to give a unique name.

Comment: well you can make a model (table) to map the UUID to a name. But it is a bit "bizarre": converting parameters to strings is not per se a bi-directional operation, and might leak sensitive dat.a